# Running a function inside a `.add`

Tags: javascript

Okay so I'm adding photos to a `Observable` with `.add` but i need to run a function/request to fetch the `UserNameFeed` information, the question is can i do this from with in the `.add`

```
var Photo = Observable();
Photo.add({
    photoDateFeed: element.theDate, 
    imgurl: "https://res.cloudinary.com/" + element.photos.value,
    UserFEEDid: element.userid,
    UserNameFeed: ( run a javascript function??? )
});
```

I'm not sure if this is possible

Comment: Depends on what the function is doing exactly. Calling the function is a simple as `foo()`.

Comment: Should this also be tagged `[rxjs]` or are Observables an upcoming language-native thing now? (Serious question, I don't know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in next step:

1. Implement function.
2. Call it.

Final code will look like that

```
function yourFunction(){
   var result = 'Name';// Do what you want
   return result;
}
var Photo = Observable();
Photo.add({
    photoDateFeed: element.theDate, 
    imgurl: "https://res.cloudinary.com/" + element.photos.value,
    UserFEEDid: element.userid,
    UserNameFeed: yourFunction()
});
```

If your function need accept parameters, just add in in argument list

```
function yourFunction(element){
   var result = 'Name ' + element.userid;// Do what you want
   return result;
}
var Photo = Observable();
Photo.add({
    photoDateFeed: element.theDate, 
    imgurl: "https://res.cloudinary.com/" + element.photos.value,
    UserFEEDid: element.userid,
    UserNameFeed: yourFunction(element)
});
```

If you need make async operation you must rewrite it to async style:

```
function yourFunction(element, callback){
   // get name in async
   $.ajax({
       ...
       success: function(result) {
           // Do what you want
           callback(result)
       }
   });   
}
var Photo = Observable();
yourFunction(element, function(result){
   Photo.add({
       photoDateFeed: element.theDate, 
       imgurl: "https://res.cloudinary.com/" + element.photos.value,
       UserFEEDid: element.userid,
       UserNameFeed: result
   });
});
```